# How can I make sure that when my ellipsis gets added lastindexof space it also checks its alphabet before it gets added and not special chars

Tags: javascript, string, ellipsis

The code looks like this:

```
 function TrimLength(text, maxLength) {
        text = $.trim(text);

        if (text.length > maxLength) {
            text = text.substring(0, maxLength - ellipsis.length)
            return text.substring(0, text.lastIndexOf(" ")) + ellipsis;
        }
        else
            return text;
    }
```

The problem I have is that it does the following thing:

```
hello world and an...

The curse of the gaming backlog –...
```

I want to make sure that it instead does:

```
hello world and...

The curse of the gaming backlog...
```

I guess that I need to make sure that there is alphabet char like (a,b,c,d etc..) and no special characters.

Any kind of help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You might want to start with this:

```
function cutoff(str, maxLen) {
    // no need to cut off
    if(str.length <= maxLen) {
        return str;
    }

    // find the cutoff point
    var oldPos = pos = 0;
    while(pos!==-1 && pos <= maxLen) {
        oldPos = pos;
        pos = str.indexOf(" ",pos) + 1;
    }
    if (pos>maxLen) { pos = oldPos; }
    // return cut off string with ellipsis
    return str.substring(0,pos) + "...";
}
```

which at least gives you cutoffs based on words, rather than letters. If you need additional filtering, you can add it, but this will give you a cutoff such as "The curse of the gaming backlog – ..." which doesn't look wrong, honestly.